# How does the Javascript print function work? Can I create a document using javascript and print it off?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, printing

I know you can use window.print() to print the current page... but what I want to know is can I build a document using javascript in order to populate it with data and print it off?

Just like you can have html/xml as a javascript object, can you do something similar to this:

```
var name = "Matt";
var htmlDocumentToPrint = "<html><body><div style='width:300px; height:20px; background-color:#000; text-align:center;'>My name is " + name + "</div></body></html>";

htmlDocumentToPrint.print();
```

I don't really care about adding colors all that much-- just want to format a document, populate it with data, and print it off. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.print) is a method on the window object.  If you create a document in a window using javascript, then call print on that window object, it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myWindow = window.open('','','width=200,height=100')
    myWindow.document.write("This is 'myWindow'")
    myWindow.print();
</script>
```

Example modified from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) window open example.

Comment: You can also use a hidden iframe to print hidden documents!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Chrome or Opera.  Both browsers seems to print the parent window when self.print() or window.print() are called on a hidden iFrame.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't seem to work with an iframe with height and width of 0px either...

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought:

You could create an iframe programmatically, assign the HTML to be printed, call the `print()` function on the context of the iframe.contentWindow, and then remove the iframe from the DOM:

```
function printHTML(input){
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); // create the element
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);  // insert the element to the DOM 

  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(input); // write the HTML to be printed
  iframe.contentWindow.print();  // print it
  document.body.removeChild(iframe); // remove the iframe from the DOM
}

printHTML('<h1>Test!</h1>');
```

You can test the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ezipu/edit).

Comment: Doesn't work in IE. If I remember correctly you need to focus() the window before printing it, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

print() essentially just calls up the native print dialog for a given window.

But as you're are thinking, it will work on any window or (i)frame.

thus if you write content to a frame, you can then call this to print it.

```
window.frameName.print();
```

note the only drawback (and its a big one), is that this calls up the print dialog... not the print preview window... thus the user doesn't really get a chance to see what they are printing and/or scale it to fit their printer/paper.

I personally wish that all browsers would implement the following to handle the above issue. ;-)

```
window.printPreview();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make everything invisible for media=print and then make visible only some blocks with your special code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this while the document is being loaded, you can use `document.write` to write the current document, then print it.

If the page has finished loading, you can use functions to manipulate the DOM, or preferably use a library such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org), then print the current document.

Answer (score 0):

Jack, have you tried window.print() inside the iframe after loading the document?

Comment: YOu have to put the document somewhere in the DOM first. Either in a new window or an iFrame. Otherwise print will print the current window, not your document.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution available no need to write a function and that is - window.print()

whereever you want to use it just put - onClick="window.print();"

Example

```
<a href="" onClick="window.print();">Print</a>
```

I testes it every browser and it works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches to printing two of which will work.

1. Print the entire window: `window.print();` will work.
2. Print only a specific frame: `window.parent._frame_id_.print();` will work.
3. Print a `documentFragment` will not work (at least in Firefox):
   `document.createDocumentFragment().print();//undefined`